# Как записать результат выполнения команды в файл и добавить произвольный текст в одной команде Linux?

Tags: linux, консоль

Хочу записать в файл результат выполнения uname -a и какой-то "sometext" одной командой, пробовал разные конструкции, не выходит.
К примеру:

```
uname -a » concept.1 |echo 'sometext » file.1
```

Или:

```
echo uname -a » '\n sometext\n blabla' file.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

двумя строками

```
uname -a >file && echo some text >>file
```

или

```
(uname -a && echo some text) >file
```

в одну строку

```
(uname -a && echo some text)| tr -d '\n' >file
```

Comment: tr -d '\n' >file - эта часть не работает. Все в одну строку.

Comment: для этого и привел если надо без перевода строки